# One spot and distance known, Second spot unknown

Tags: analytic-geometry

I know the coordinates of points E and Q, so I know their euclidean distance L.
I'm looking for the point W with coordinates (a,b) related to other known values?

[image: http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/8493/geometry1.jpg]

Comment: You know *r* as well, right? Or do you want the answer in terms of *r*

Comment: Also, that link is opening up all sorts of popups on my browser. Please use the "add image" button.

Comment: No, I know *r* . I'm looking for the *a* and *b* in terms of the others.

Comment: Assume the $E$ is the origin, for a moment.
$\vec{EQ}=\binom{x}{y}=L\binom{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$.
Then use vector addition: $\vec{EW}=\vec{EQ}+\vec{QW}$. If $E$ is not the origin, shift the result by $\vec{E}= \binom{e_1}{e_2}$. (all assuming $\theta$ is also known...)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you know $\theta$, the coordinates $(x,y)$ of $Q$, and $r$.  The angle of rotation from a vertical line through $Q$ to $\overline{QW}$ is also $\theta$, so if we take the point that is $r$ above $Q$ and rotate it by $\theta$ about $Q$, we'll get $W$.  That means $$W=(a,b)=(x-r\sin\theta,y+r\cos\theta).$$